# Retrieving the first element of a list nested in another list

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
addresses = [['Jim', 543, 65], ['Jack', 4376, 23], ['Hank', 764, 43]]
print addresses[0:][0]  # I want this to return: ['Jim', 'Jack', 'Hank']`
```

How would I make this print out only the names in `addresses`?

I used this:

```
for item in addresses:
    print item[0]
```

Comment: I've never seen a question get so many answers and downvotes so quickly.

Comment: @Kupiakos, you mean, so many _answers_, right?

Comment: I was watching the race of people trying to respond first lol

Comment: Can't believe-9 with 9 answers in less than √9 minutes

Answer (score 3):

One more solution with `map`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x[0], addresses)))
['Jim', 'Jack', 'Hank']
```

Or you could use `operator.itemgetter(0)` as @Kupiakos suggested in the comment:

```
from operator import itemgetter(0)
print(list(map(itemgetter(0), addresses)))
['Jim', 'Jack', 'Hank']
```

**Timing**:

```
In [648]: %timeit list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), addresses))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 µs per loop

In [649]: %timeit list(map(lambda x: x[0], addresses))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 µs per loop
```

Comment: You can also use `operator.itemgetter(0)` instead of a lambda for more speed.

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(map(itemgetter(0), addresses))
```

This selects the first item from each element in `addresses` and creates a new list from it. `itemgetter(0)` is faster than a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

```
print("\n".join(zip(*addresses)[0]))
#or maybe just 
print(zip(*addresses)[0])
```

might as well throw one more into the ring :P

Answer (score 0):

```
print([x[0] for x in addresses])
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to be to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

`names = [a[0] for a in addresses]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`list comprehension`](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) to get the first item (`item[0]`) from each list in your address list. Then you just print it. From the REPL:

```
>>> addresses = [['Jim', 543, 65], ['Jack', 4376, 23], ['Hank', 764, 43]]
>>> [item[0] for item in addresses]
['Jim', 'Jack', 'Hank']
>>> for name in [item[0] for item in addresses]:
...     print(name) 
... 
Jim
Jack
Hank
```

Python's [print](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print) lets you shorthand this to:

```
print([item[0] for item in addresses])
```

Comment: IIRC, they're called list comprehensions, or generator comprehensions, or dictionary comprehensions, or set comprehensions, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> names = [sublist[0] for sublist in addresses]
>>> names
['Jim', 'Jack', 'Hank']
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
print [a[0] for a in addresses]
```

Here `a` is a subarray and `a[0]` is its first element.